# Qt creator debug mode can not run on Ubuntu20

Tags: ubuntu, qt5, qt-creator

[image] When I try to debug my application I observed this dialog and debug can not reach breakpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build your application in debug mode. For that you need to set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` cmake variable to `Debug`, see [creator build settings](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings-cmake.html). This adds `-g` flag to `gcc`, which instructs it to add debug information to the binary.